# how to match an arbitrary number of occurrences of a word with a regular expression

Tags: regex

How can you match multiple occurrences of a string with a regular expression? For example suppose I wish to match any of the following:

```
abc
abcabc
abcabcabc
```

and so on.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I am using javascript, which I believe employs the usual unix regex syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose `abc` is a known string.
use this pattern

```
((?:abc)+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/153)

or use this pattern if `abc` is unknown, subpattern #1

```
^((\w+?)\2*)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/154)

Comment: You can throw away the outer most capturing group in the second pattern, since you are anchoring it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In Python:

```
In [1]: 'abcabcabc'.count('abc')
Out[1]: 3
```